# Swift Codable: Include dictionary key as property in decoded Codable object

Tags: json, swift, swift5, codable

I have a JSON object as such:

```
{
    "red":
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3
        }
    "yellow":
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3
        }
    "blue":
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3
        }
}
```

I decode each of these into a `Color` object marked as `Codable`.

I would like to include the key of the object as a property of the object itself, such that I can differentiate between the keys to provide supplementary information, such as having a function that can provide a color to pair with the object (e.g. for 'red', pair it with 'blue').

How can I include the dictionary key as a property on the `Codable` object itself?

Comment: Why do you think the keys aren't already included in the object? You've got a dictionary with keys *red*, *yellow*, and *blue*. I guess you could add another item called *keys* to the dictionary, and make it's value an array of strings that are they keys, but what would be the point of that?

Comment: As I pass around the various Color objects, I'd like to be able to get their 'pair' info directly from that object, rather than having to work through the top-level one. Effectively--how can I know that "yellow" is actually Yellow and not Red?

Comment: Yellow is the one whose key is *yellow*, no? Perhaps it'd be helpful if you edit to add a concrete example of what you'd like to do. It could be that there's a real problem to solve here and it's just not coming through in your question as it stands, or it might be that just changing your perspective a bit will help.

Comment: So assume the top level object is ColorTable, which contains a set of Colors. The Color object for Yellow is just a generic Color with a=1, b=1, c=1, but I have no way to tell that apart from Red in a function that takes in just a Color object (as I am NOT passing around the full ColorTable). Apologies if I'm missing something really obvious here :/

Comment: Why would a function that just takes a generic color care about the difference between red and yellow? If it does, that seems like a problem. It's like calling `pow(_:_:)` to calculate an exponent -- the function doesn't care which numbers you give it, it just does it's thing, and it's up to the caller to put the result in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @vadian answer, you could try this approach, using `init(from decoder: Decoder)` to decode the json data,
and a `Colour` struct
with a `name` and `id` that you can use.

```
struct ColorResponse: Decodable {
    var red: Colour
    var yellow: Colour
    var blue: Colour
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case red,yellow,blue
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        red = try container.decode(Colour.self, forKey: .red)
        red.name = "red"
        yellow = try container.decode(Colour.self, forKey: .yellow)
        yellow.name = "yellow"
        blue = try container.decode(Colour.self, forKey: .blue)
        blue.name = "blue"
    }
}

struct Colour: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var a, b, c : Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a,b,c
    }
}

struct ColorView: View {
    @State var colour: Colour
    
    var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text(colour.name)
           Text("\(colour.a)")
           Text("\(colour.b)")
           Text("\(colour.c)")
       }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var colours: [Colour] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(colours) { col in
            ColorView(colour: col)
        }
        .onAppear {
            let json = """
            {
                "red":  {  "a": 1, "b": 2,  "c": 3  },
                "yellow": {  "a": 1, "b": 2,  "c": 3  },
                "blue":  {  "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3  }
            }
            """
            // simulated API data
            let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
            do {
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(ColorResponse.self, from: data)
                colours.append(results.blue)
                colours.append(results.red)
                colours.append(results.yellow)
                colours.forEach{print("---> colours: \($0)")}
            } catch {
                print("\n---> decoding error: \n \(error)\n")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to add a temporary struct for the color object, then decode the dictionary as `[String:Temp]` and map the data to the real struct. As `Color` is part of `SwiftUI` I named the struct `MyColor`

```
struct Temp: Decodable { let a, b, c : Int }

struct Root : Decodable {
    let colors : [MyColor]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let colorData = try container.decode([String:Temp].self)
        colors = colorData.map{ MyColor(name: $0.key, a: $0.value.a, b: $0.value.b, c: $0.value.c) }
    }
}

struct MyColor : Decodable {
    let name: String
    let a, b, c : Int
}
```

Then decode

```
JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self...
```

However if the keys are static drop the `Temp` struct and use this

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let red : MyColor
    let yellow : MyColor
    let blue : MyColor
}

struct MyColor : Decodable {
    let a, b, c : Int
}
```

Comment: I think this may be onto something... colors is not actually an array of [MyColor] but instead a bunch of properties: so Root would have "yellow", "red" and "blue" as properties.

Comment: This is only possible if the keys are static which means they have always the same names.

Comment: The bottom example you have with static names is exactly what it is. I pass around MyColor objects and need to be able to get back the fact its 'red' and not 'blue' but when just using a MyColor object in a function, I can't seem to do that.